# To stop reloading of page on selectedindex change in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a nested gridview, in Parent grid view I have implemented expand and collapse functionality to display child grid view in which I have three columns out of which 2nd column is a dropdown and three column is a status.

On expansion, the child gridview is getting opened and I want that whenever I am changing the dropdown value (which is in child gridview), the third column (which is also in Childgridview) changes from its value. I am able to do so but the whole page is getting reloaded and again coming as the intial that is in collapse manner.

Can anyone tell me how to make my child grid view remain open and should not get reload. I have even tried Update Panel but not working.

[image]

Comment: did you try to prevent default on dropdown change?

Comment: how can it be helpful..?

Comment: well, as far as i understand: after you select an option in dropdown - page reloads. so maybe you could prevent that default functionality on your dropdown.. doc [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)